# C++ semantic issue, const value_type to pointer*

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to get this C++ method to return an array of b2Fixture instances. It iterates of a series of JRContact instances, which are defined like:

```
struct JRContact {
    b2Fixture *fixtureA;
    b2Fixture *fixtureB;
    bool operator==(const JRContact& other) const
    {
        return (fixtureA == other.fixtureA) && (fixtureB == other.fixtureB);
    }
};
```

n.b. I'm a total stranger to C++, don't hesitate to mention weird things I might have done in that code ;-)

The following fails to compile (XCode compiler on MacOS), see errors in comments:

```
id AbstractContactListener::getFixturesOfTypeCollidingWithFixture(b2Fixture *fix, int type){

    std::vector<b2Fixture> fixtures;

    std::vector<JRContact>::iterator ct;
    JRContact contact;

    for (ct = _contacts.begin(); ct != _contacts.end(); ct++){

        contact = *ct;

        if ( 
                ( (fix == contact.fixtureA) || (fix == contact.fixtureB) ) &&
                ( contactContainsType(contact, type) )
            ){

            if (fix == contact.fixtureA) {

                // error: Semantic Issue: Reference to type 'const value_type' (aka 'const b2Fixture') could not bind to an lvalue of type 'b2Fixture *'

                fixtures.push_back(contact.fixtureB);
            }

            else {

                // error: Semantic Issue: Reference to type 'const value_type' (aka 'const b2Fixture') could not bind to an lvalue of type 'b2Fixture *'
                fixtures.push_back(contact.fixtureA);
            }
        }
    }

    // error: Semantic Issue: No viable conversion from 'std::vector<b2Fixture>' to 'id'
    return fixtures;
}
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change :

```
std::vector<b2Fixture> fixtures;
```

to :

```
std::vector<b2Fixture *> fixtures;
```

About the return type you can change it either to `void*` or `std::vector<b2Fixture *> *` and use : `return &fixtures;`

But pay attention the your vector is local so allocate it for not returning a pointer to an invalid location. (And ofcourse remember to free it when you done using it).

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what you want to do, but the problem is you're telling the compiler that `AbstractContactListener::getFixturesOfTypeCollidingWithFixture` will return an `id` and you're instead returning an `std::vector<b2Fixture>`.

From the name of the function, I guess you might want to return a `vector`, so change the signature to:

```
std::vector<b2Fixture> AbstractContactListener::getFixturesOfTypeCollidingWithFixture
                                                      (b2Fixture *fix, int type)
```

You're also pushing pointers in your vector when you should be pushing objects:

```
fixtures.push_back(*(contact.fixtureB));
```

Answer (score 1):

The vector `fixtures` holds `b2Fixture` instances, but the `contact.fixtureA` is a `b2Fixture*`.

Either:

- dereference it:

  ```
  fixtures.push_back(*(contact.fixtureA)); // Same for 'fixtureB'.
  ```

  or,
- change the type of `fixtures`:

  ```
  std::vector<b2Fixture*> fixtures;
  ```

There is also a mismatch between the function return type and what is actually being returned. If you want to return `fixtures`, have the return type match the type of `fixtures`.